# SIGABRT Error: Unknown class _TtC11Foodtracker14ViewController in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, sigabrt

Okay, so I have been working through the Apple iOS Getting started with Swift Tutorial and am on the "Implementing Navigation" section. I have run into an issue where after control-dragging the "+" bar button item, the apple uses the forced crash SIGABRT with an error identifier as "Unknown Class"

Any ideas what I might be dealing with? It's in using the Show Segue. I've retraced my steps up to the point where I am at and simply can not determine the cause of the error.

I have attempted to delete the connection in the "Connection Inspector" and deleting the button, navigation, etc... and rebuilding, cleaning with no luck. Any guidance would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm adding images to help show what I see in Xcode.
[image: View of my current storyboard scene]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you assign a class to a VC ( In IB ) which is not inside your target or the module is set to none

[image]

Comment: Okay, so the tutorial doesn't make this clear. How would you actually implement it? I has supposed that the tutorial would take these things into account but it doesn't seem much help for handling this error event.

Comment: I have added an image of my storyboard with identity inspector open. Maybe this will help with diagnosing the issue.

Comment: move the cursor in class field then click Enter

Comment: Still the same error when compiled. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Here it is: [foodtracker gitrepo](https://github.com/skerr92/foodtracker)

Comment: You only missed to set mealViewController as the class and some other configs see here http://www.mediafire.com/file/fcmxmfm4pbt586z/Foodtracker.zip/file